# Unable to get the count of rows in HTML table using scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

Unable to get the count of rows in HTML table using scrapy.

I have a html document like the below:

```
<TITLE>Title of Mbean</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="left"><H2>Array View</H2></TD>
<TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN="top">[JDMK5.0_r16]</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
<UL type="disc"><LI><B>MBean Name:</B> Name of MBean</LI>
<LI><B>MBean Attribute:</B> product list</LI>
<LI><B>Array of:</B> java.lang.String</LI>
</UL>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%"><TR>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT"><A HREF="Object name">Back to MBean View</A></TD>
<TD ALIGN="RIGHT"><A HREF="/">Back to Agent View</A></TD>
</TR></TABLE>
<HR>
<A NAME="Top"></A>
<TABLE ALIGN="center" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="3">
<TR>
<TH WIDTH="10%"> Element at </TH>
<TH WIDTH="7%"> Access </TH>
<TH WIDTH="35%"> Value </TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="center">0</TD><TD ALIGN="center">RO</TD>
<TD>this is the value</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="center">0</TD><TD ALIGN="center">RO</TD>
<TD>this is the second value</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and when i specify the following to try and count of rows in the table using the following xpath using scrapy and nothing is returned:

```
hxs = Selector(response)

loader = XPathItemLoader(WebscraperItem(), selector=hxs)
loader.add_xpath('tablecount', 'count(/HTML/BODY/HR/TABLE/TR)')
yield loader.load_item()
```

I have tried the xpath in Oxygen, and can see that the xpath works OK, but just not within scrapy, has anyone got any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Don't trust the browser tools because the browser fixes the broken html adding/removing tags and the xpath tools give you a full path which is not recommended. It's better to just build the expression with the elements you care/need, just as Guy pointed out in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've copied your html to a local file called in.html and:

```
$ scrapy shell in.html
...
>>> from scrapy.item import Item, Field
>>> class WebscraperItem(Item): tablecount = Field()
...
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
>>> loader = XPathItemLoader(WebscraperItem(), selector=sel)
>>> loader.add_xpath('tablecount', 'count(//table/tr)')
>>> loader.load_item()
{'tablecount': [u'5.0']}
```